# Android: Pause the thread for several seconds

Tags: android, multithreading

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
List<Future<Object>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

// submit tasks
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    results.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask()));
}

...

// stop the pool from accepting new tasks
exec.shutdown();

// wait for results
for(Future<Object> result: results) {
    Object obj = result.get();
}


class ThreadTask implements Callable<Object> {

    public Object call() {
        // execute download
        //Inside this method I need to pause the thread for several seconds
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

As shown above in the comment I need to pause the thread for several seconds. Hope you can help me with this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`Thread.sleep(timeInMillis)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) - that will pause the current thread.

So:

```
Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5 seconds
```

Obviously you shouldn't do this from a UI thread, or your whole UI will freeze...

Note that this simple approach won't allow the thread to be woken up other by interrupting it. If you want to be able to wake it up early, you could use `Object.wait()` on a monitor which is accessible to whichever code needs to wake it up; that code could use `Object.notify()` to wake the waiting thread up. (Alternatively, use a higher-level abstraction such as [`Condition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) or [`Semaphore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).)

Answer (score 0):

you could implement a new thread, which is not the UI thread..

something like this might do it for you..

```
class ThreadTask implements Callable<Object> {

public Object call() {
Thread createdToWait= new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                    //---some code

                    sleep(1000);//call this function to pause the execution of this thread

                    //---code to be executed after the pause
        }
    };
    createdToWait.start();
 return result;
}
```